# Access is denied, at attr ( http://localhost/JQuery.min.js). On IE 11.0.9600.19266

Tags: internet-explorer

I have updated my internet explore in windows 7 and it broke the angularjs web application.

It was working fine with IE 11.0.9600.19236.
IE auto upgraded with windows 7 updates.

Now I'm facing issue with the application which was raining fine with previous version of IE.

Following is the error message in getting on browser console.

Access is denied, at attr (http://localhost/.../JQuery.min.js).

There is no cross domain call, and JQuery script file is in same domain.

Could you please help what could be the cause?

Thank you,
Ajay Verma

Comment: Please check the js file, make sure you have the permissions to access the file, you could refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2623670/access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-f). Then, you could try to run the IE as Administrator or try to disable "Enable Protected Mode" in the security tab of IE Options.

Comment: @Zhi Lv :  Yes, I have access to file. I have tried all other suggestions given by you but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and solutions. It is an issue with Microsoft latest update for IE version 11.0.9600.196266. They release following fix :
KB449113
and after installing fix, it's working fine.

Comment: Do you have a link to this KB?

Comment: It's actually KB4491113.